# Keras for Python can't be installed using Anaconda

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

I would like to install the libaray Keras for machine learning in Python (https://keras.io/).
I use Anaconda (as an Administrator) and I tried the following command.

```
(base) C:\Users\wi9632>conda install keras
```

And here is the output with the error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - keras -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8.5

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

Can you tell me what I have to do in order to install Keras? If I understand correctly, the version of my Python environment is to new?
I'd appreciate every comment.

Does nobody have an idea what I can do? I'd be quite happy about it.

Update: I tried it by using the command:

> conda install -c conda-forge keras (see https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras)
> and I tried to install the packages by using the GUI of Anaconda. Both yielded the same error message.

Comment: Why didn't you just install an older python version? Did you check for conda Updates?

Comment: Thanks Max for your comment. Basically I did 'conda update conda' before 'conda install keras' but the problem still occurs.

Comment: So basically I think it is not advicable in general to install an older version of something because as far as i know you should always have the latest version of a programming language and for me it is weird that a popular package is only compatible to older Python versions. I assume that there is another thing that causes this problem. Do you have any ideas or what is your take on that? I'd be happy about your inputs

Comment: It seems, keras does not yet support python 3.8 directly. A workaround is to install tensorflow and use tensorflow.keras: [Source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14186)

Comment: Thanks Max for your answer and effort. Is TensorFlow not thing google library? I bascially want to use Keras and not TensorFlow

Comment: Keras is an API using tensorflow. So u'd use tensorflow anyway :)

Comment: Hi Max. Thanks for your answer. I tried to install Tensorflow with
"conda install tensorflow" and I receive a similr error message:
"UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - tensorflow -> python[version='3.5.*|3.6.*|3.7.*']

Your python: python=3.8.5"

Comment: It is extremely strange that Python does not seem to have backwards compatibility with (some important) 'older' packages. The elements of older Python versions (e.g. 3.7) should be included in the newer Python versions. I have never seen anything like that in any programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with `conda` rather than with `keras`, see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14186). Using `pip` instead of `conda` might resolve your problem.

However, I'd discourage using `keras` anyway as now using `tf.keras` is the recommended way of working with Keras, see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0):

> Keras 2.3.0 is the first release of multi-backend Keras that supports
> TensorFlow 2.0. It maintains compatibility with TensorFlow 1.14, 1.13,
> as well as Theano and CNTK.
>
> This release brings the API in sync with the tf.keras API as of
> TensorFlow 2.0. However note that it does not support most TensorFlow
> 2.0 features, in particular eager execution. If you need these features, use tf.keras.
>
> This is also the last major release of multi-backend Keras. Going
> forward, we recommend that users consider switching their Keras code
> to tf.keras in TensorFlow 2.0.

So if `conda install tensorflow` works for you, just replace any appearance of `keras` with `tf.keras` in your code. This way, there is no need to install `keras` separately.

Comment: Thanks Alperino for your comment. I tried to install Tensorflow with "conda install tensorflow" and I receive a similr error message: "UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment: Specifications: - tensorflow -> python[version='3.5.*|3.6.*|3.7.*'] Your python: python=3.8.5"

Comment: How can I use pip with Anaconda?

Comment: If ``conda install tensorflow`` won't work, you can replace ``conda`` with ``pip``, i.e. use ``pip install tensorflow`` instead.